Библиотека VisaComLib
Нужна позарез библиотека VisaComLib.dll третьей версии. Подскажите где ее найти?
Среда:

Win10
C#

Используется в проекте доставшемся по наследству.
Буду весьма благодарен....

не это ли? https://www.keysight.com/zz/en/lib/software-detail/computer-software/io-libraries-suite-downloads-2175637.html

"Sorry, you have been blocked"
